# AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionGD' object has no attribute 'net_input' Why do I get this error? I define net_input

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assigning the petal length and petal width of the 150 flower samples to Matrix X 
# Class labels of the flower to vector y 

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]]
y = iris.target
print('Class labels:', np.unique(y))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1, stratify=y)

print('Labels counts in y:', np.bincount(y))
print('Labels counts in y_train:', np.bincount(y_train))
print ('Labels counts in y_test:', np.bincount(y_test))

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)

class LogisticRegressionGD(object):
    """Logistic Regression Classifier using gradient descent.

    Parameters
    ------------
    eta : float
        Learning rate (between 0.0 and 1.0)
    n_iter : int
        Passes over the training dataset
    random_state : int
        Random number generator seed for random weight initialization

    Attributes
    ------------
    w_ : 1d-array
        Weights after fitting.
    cost_ : list
        Sum-of-squares cost function value in each epoch.

    """
    def __init__(self, eta=0.05, n_iter=100, random_state=1):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.random_state = random_state
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        """ Fit training data.

        Parameters
        ------------
        X : {array-like}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and 
            n_features is the number of features.
        y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
            Target values

        Returns
        ------------
        self : object

        """
        rgen = np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.w_ = rgen.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=1 + X.shape[1])
        self.cost_ = []

        for i in range(self.n_iter):
            net_input = self.net_input(X)
            output = self.activation(net_input)
            errors = (y - output)
            self.w_[1:] += self.eta * X.T.dot(errors)
            self.w_[0] += self.eta * errors.sum()

            # note that we compute the logistic 'cost' now
            # instead of the sum of the squared errors cost
            cost = (-y.dot(np.log(output)) - ((1 - y).dot(np.log(1 - output))))
            self.cost_.append(cost)
            return self
        
        def net_input(self, X):
            """Calculate net input"""
            return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

        def activation(self, z):
            """Compute logistic sigmoid activation"""
            return 1. / (1. + (np.clip(z, -250, 250)))

        def predict(self, X):
            """Return class label after unit step"""
            return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0,  1, 0)
            # equivalent to: 
            # return np.where(self.activation(self.net_input(X)) >= 0.5, 1, 0)

# Considering only Iris-setosa and Iris-versicolor (Classes 0 and 1)
X_train_01_subset = X_train[(y_train == 0) | (y_train == 1)]
y_train_01_subset = y_train[(y_train == 0) | (y_train == 1)]
lrgd = LogisticRegressionGD(eta=0.05, n_iter=1000, random_state=1)
lrgd.fit(X_train_01_subset, y_train_01_subset)
plot_decision_regions(X=X_train_01_subset, y=y_train_01_subset, classifier=lrgd)
plt.xlabel('petal length [standardized]')
plt.ylabel('petal width [standardized]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

After running that, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/Ch3LogisticRegressionGD.py", line 102, in <module>
    lrgd.fit(X_train_01_subset, y_train_01_subset)
  File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/Ch3LogisticRegressionGD.py", line 72, in fit
    net_input = self.net_input(X)
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionGD' object has no attribute 'net_input'
```

I looked at other people who asked similar questions and I found that usually this error message comes about because the attribute is not defined. However, doesn't line 72 - net_input = self.net_input(X) define net_input?

Comment: No, that line `net_input = self.net_input(X)` attempts to assign the (defined) attribute to a (function) local variable.  That line only works if previously you done a `def net_input(self,x):...` method definition.  Instead you define `net_input` as a function local to the `fit` method.

Comment: I suspect the indent of the methods, `net_input` and follow is wrong.

Comment: You know at first I thought it was an indent error myself. After reading your first comment, I'm thinking I may need to put the def net_input(self, x) method definition above the fit method...

Comment: @DK: If the code in the question is what you actually run then it's an indentation error. The `def net_input(self, X):` line is indented 4 spaces more than `def fit(self, X, y):`, i.e., it is only defined inside the `fit` fucntion.